# Simple Quiz in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am taking this vb general education class which is totally non related to my major. I am really struggling here with one of our assignments. The assignment is to create a simple quiz consisting of 3 questions, and the program is supposed to calculate the score and the percentage of the participant. I have written the following code so far, but it doesn't execute right. Can anyone help me with this please? Another thing I can't figure out is that how to make one of the textboxs' case insensitive. Any help would be great!

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim FirstAnswer As Integer = 2
    Dim SecondAnswer As String = "Barak Obama"
    Dim ThirdAnswer As String = "Florida"
    Dim CorrectAnswer As Double = 0
    Dim Num1 As Double = CDbl(lblCorrectAnswer.Text)
    Dim Percent As Double
    Percent = Num1 / 3 * 100

    If txtSum.Text = FirstAnswer And txtPresident.Text = SecondAnswer And txtImpoertantQues.Text = ThirdAnswer Then
        lblCorrectAnswer.Text = CorrectAnswer + 3
        txtSum.BackColor = Color.Green
        txtSum.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtPresident.BackColor = Color.Green
        txtPresident.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtImpoertantQues.BackColor = Color.Green
        txtImpoertantQues.ForeColor = Color.White
        lblPrecent.Text = Percent.ToString("##.00") & "%"
    ElseIf txtSum.Text = FirstAnswer And txtImpoertantQues.Text = ThirdAnswer Then
        lblCorrectAnswer.Text = CorrectAnswer + 2
        txtSum.BackColor = Color.Green
        txtSum.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtImpoertantQues.BackColor = Color.Green
        txtImpoertantQues.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtPresident.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtPresident.ForeColor = Color.White
        lblPrecent.Text = Percent.ToString("##.00") & "%"
    ElseIf txtSum.Text = FirstAnswer Then
        lblCorrectAnswer.Text = CorrectAnswer + 1
        txtSum.BackColor = Color.Green
        txtSum.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtPresident.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtPresident.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtImpoertantQues.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtImpoertantQues.ForeColor = Color.White
        lblPrecent.Text = Percent.ToString("##.00") & "%"
    ElseIf txtSum.Text = FirstAnswer And txtPresident.Text = SecondAnswer Then
        lblCorrectAnswer.Text = CorrectAnswer + 2
        txtSum.BackColor = Color.Green
        txtSum.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtPresident.BackColor = Color.Green
        txtPresident.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtImpoertantQues.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtImpoertantQues.ForeColor = Color.White
        lblPrecent.Text = Percent.ToString("##.00") & "%"
    ElseIf txtPresident.Text = SecondAnswer And txtImpoertantQues.Text = ThirdAnswer Then
        lblCorrectAnswer.Text = CorrectAnswer + 2
        txtPresident.BackColor = Color.Green
        txtPresident.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtImpoertantQues.BackColor = Color.Green
        txtImpoertantQues.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtSum.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtSum.ForeColor = Color.White
        lblPrecent.Text = Percent.ToString("##.00") & "%"
    ElseIf txtPresident.Text = SecondAnswer Then
        lblCorrectAnswer.Text = CorrectAnswer + 1
        txtPresident.BackColor = Color.Green
        txtPresident.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtSum.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtSum.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtImpoertantQues.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtImpoertantQues.ForeColor = Color.White
        lblPrecent.Text = Percent.ToString("##.00") & "%"
    ElseIf txtImpoertantQues.Text = ThirdAnswer Then
        lblCorrectAnswer.Text = CorrectAnswer + 1
        txtImpoertantQues.BackColor = Color.Green
        txtImpoertantQues.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtSum.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtSum.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtPresident.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtPresident.ForeColor = Color.White
        lblPrecent.Text = Percent.ToString("##.00") & "%"
    Else
        lblCorrectAnswer.Text = CorrectAnswer = 0
        lblPrecent .Text = 0
        txtSum.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtSum.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtPresident.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtPresident.ForeColor = Color.White
        txtImpoertantQues.BackColor = Color.Red
        txtImpoertantQues.ForeColor = Color.White
    End If

    If txtSum.Text = Nothing Or txtPresident.Text = Nothing Or txtPresident.Text = Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR! Please enter an aswer.")
    End If
```

Comment: *it doesn't execute right* is not a meaningful problem description. In what way **specifically** does it **not execute right**? What happens when you step through it in the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

There are three questions so there must be three If...ElseIf...Else or If..Else.
You should not include the scoring of the other questions inside the ElseIf because once the program returns true in either of the If or ElseIf in your conditions then the If..Else terminates and not execute the rest of the ElseIf..

it should be like this for example,

```
if txtsum.text=.... then
elseif
else
end if

if txtpresident.text=... then
else
end if

if txtImpoertantQues.Text=... then
else
end if
```

rest assured, it will execute just as you wanted...
Or probably like this...

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim FirstAnswer As Integer = 2
    Dim SecondAnswer As String = "Barak Obama"
    Dim ThirdAnswer As String = "Florida"
    Dim CorrectAnswer As Double = 0
    Dim Num1 As Double = CDbl(lblCorrectAnswer.Text)
    Dim Percent As Double
    Percent = Num1 / 3 * 100
    If txtSum.Text = Nothing Or txtPresident.Text = Nothing Or txtPresident.Text = Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR! Please enter an aswer.")
        'when everything is empty then the rest won't be executed
        'instead, the program prompts the user to enter an answer
    Else
        If txtSum.Text = FirstAnswer Then
            CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer + 1 'added points
            txtSum.BackColor = Color.Green
            txtSum.ForeColor = Color.White
            lblPrecent.Text = Percent.ToString("##.00") & "%"
        End If

        If txtSum.Text = FirstAnswer Then
            CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer + 1 'added points
            txtSum.BackColor = Color.Green
            txtSum.ForeColor = Color.White
            lblPrecent.Text = Percent.ToString("##.00") & "%"
        End If

        If txtImpoertantQues.Text = ThirdAnswer Then
            CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer + 1 'added points
            txtImpoertantQues.BackColor = Color.Green
            txtImpoertantQues.ForeColor = Color.White
            lblPrecent.Text = Percent.ToString("##.00") & "%"
        End If

        lblCorrectAnswer.Text = CorrectAnswer 'displays the total score

    End If 'end of empty field validation
End Sub
```